# Using MKMapView, Core Location, and Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, core-location

So I'm in the process of learning core data and core location and I'm a little stuck on how to save core location data with core data. What I'm trying to do is this: the user types in an address and it is displayed in MKMapView (I've got this part down), then the user pushes a button 'save' and it saves the location, dismisses the screen and goes back to the previous screen (which is a UITableView) and adds that location to the table.

How should my save method look?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the location from your map, lat long

1. use for dealing with core data easier [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)
2. create MapLocation "Entity" in your db schema
   . create property "lat", type float
   . create property "long", type float
3. create file nsManagedObject for your "Entity"
4. where you want to save your location:

   Location *locationInsert = [Location mr_createEntity];
   locationInsert.lat = myLat;
   locationInsert.long = myLong;

   //Save

   NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
                [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];